# Raw SQL works, using flask-mysql get syntax error

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am building an application with Flask/mysql. I have a raw SQL script needed to seed the database. If I enter a SQL shell and run the command, it works without issues. When I run it from Flask, I am getting an error:

```
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS board_symbol; \n        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS symbol; \n      ' at line 2")
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

My flask application is very simple, two files. The first, app.py:

```
from flask import Flask 

from db import create_db, seed_db 

app = Flask(__name__)

db = create_db(app)
conn = db.connect() 

seed_db(conn)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello world!"
```

The second, db.py:

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL 

def create_db(app):
    app.config["MYSQL_DATABASE_USER"] = "root" 
    app.config["MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD"] = "mysqluser" 
    app.config["MYSQL_DATABASE_DB"] = "fault_tree" 
    app.config["MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST"] = "localhost"  

    mysql = MySQL()
    mysql.init_app(app)
    return mysql 

def seed_db(conn):
    try:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS symbol_connection; 
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS board_symbol; 
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS symbol; 
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS board; 
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS symbol_type; 
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS board ( 
            id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
            name VARCHAR(100),
            description VARCHAR(500),
            PRIMARY KEY(id)
        );
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS symbol_type (
            id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
            type VARCHAR(30),
            PRIMARY KEY(id)
        );
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS symbol (
            id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
            name VARCHAR(100),
            description VARCHAR(200),
            type INT,
            child_board INT,
            PRIMARY KEY(id),
            FOREIGN KEY(type) REFERENCES symbol_type(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
            FOREIGN KEY(child_board) REFERENCES board(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
        );
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS board_symbol (
            board_id INTEGER,
            symbol_id INTEGER,
            FOREIGN KEY(board_id) REFERENCES board(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
            FOREIGN KEY(symbol_id) REFERENCES symbol(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
            PRIMARY KEY(board_id, symbol_id)
        );
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS symbol_connection (
            board_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
            start_symbol INT NOT NULL, 
            destination_symbol INT NOT NULL, 
            PRIMARY KEY(start_symbol, destination_symbol),
            FOREIGN KEY(board_id) REFERENCES board(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
            FOREIGN KEY(start_symbol) REFERENCES symbol(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
            FOREIGN KEY(destination_symbol) REFERENCES symbol(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
        );
        INSERT INTO board(name, description) VALUES('test_board', 'test_board');
        INSERT INTO symbol_type(type) VALUES('Event/basic');
        INSERT INTO symbol_type(type) VALUES('Event/conditioning');
        INSERT INTO symbol_type(type) VALUES('Event/intermediate');
        INSERT INTO symbol_type(type) VALUES('Event/remote basic');
        INSERT INTO symbol_type(type) VALUES('Event/underdeveloped');
        INSERT INTO symbol_type(type) VALUES('Gate/and');
        INSERT INTO symbol_type(type) VALUES('Gate/or');
        INSERT INTO symbol_type(type) VALUES('Gate/priority and');
        INSERT INTO symbol_type(type) VALUES('Gate/priority or');
        INSERT INTO symbol_type(type) VALUES('Gate/exclusive or');
        INSERT INTO symbol_type(type) VALUES('Transfer');
        INSERT INTO symbol(name, description, type) VALUES('Test event', 'test basic event', 1);
        INSERT INTO symbol(name, description, type) VALUES('Test and gate', 'test and gate', 6);
        INSERT INTO symbol(name, description, type) VALUES('Test intermediate event', 'test int event', 3);
        INSERT INTO symbol(name, description, type) VALUES('Test or gate', 'test or gate', 7);
        INSERT INTO board_symbol(board_id, symbol_id) VALUES(1, 1);
        INSERT INTO board_symbol(board_id, symbol_id) VALUES(1, 2);
        INSERT INTO board_symbol(board_id, symbol_id) VALUES(1, 3);
        INSERT INTO board_symbol(board_id, symbol_id) VALUES(1, 4);
        INSERT INTO symbol_connection(board_id, start_symbol, destination_symbol) VALUES(1, 1, 2);
        INSERT INTO symbol_connection(board_id, start_symbol, destination_symbol) VALUES(1, 1, 3);
        INSERT INTO symbol_connection(board_id, start_symbol, destination_symbol) VALUES(1, 3, 4);
        SELECT * FROM symbol_connection;
        SELECT * FROM symbol_type;
        SELECT * FROM board_symbol;
        SELECT * FROM symbol;
        SELECT * FROM board;
        """)
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        print(data)
    except Exception as e: 
        print(e)
        # raise Exception("Problem initializing MySQL database - check that fault_tree database exists and user root has access")
```

This is set up using a local database named fault_tree, with creds as listed in db.py if helpful for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

By default, you can only do one SQL statement per invocation of `cursor.execute()`.

To run multiple SQL statements separated by semicolons, use `cursor.execute("""...""", multi=True)`

See https://instructobit.com/tutorial/130/Executing-multi-query-.sql-files-using-MySQL-connector-in-Python for a tutorial.